# groovy transliteration any language to latin

Tags: groovy, transliteration

I would like to do transliteration in groovy of a text string UTF to latin characters( for URL purpose).
I checked several libs and some are working other not.

Currently I'm working with this code:

```
@Grab(group='com.ibm.icu', module='icu4j', version='58.2')
import com.ibm.icu.text.Transliterator;

String cyrilic      = "ш щ ч ц х ф г я ";
String id = "Bulgarian-Latin/BGN";
String id1 = "Latin";

String latin = Transliterator.getInstance(id).transform(cyrilic);
println "ok : " + latin;
String latin1 = Transliterator.getInstance(id1).transform(cyrilic);
println "nok : " + latin1;
```

Result

```
ok : sh sht ch ts kh f g ya 
nok : š ŝ č c h f g â
```

The problem is that I'm not able to detect the correct identifier for a string.

I want to do it for an arbitrary language: Japanese, Chinese, German

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Any`:

```
@Grab(group='com.ibm.icu', module='icu4j', version='58.2')
import com.ibm.icu.text.Transliterator;

String anything = "ш щ ч ц х ф г я चंब्रिद्गॆ цамбридге كَمبرِدگِ かんぶりでげ";
String id = "Any-Latin";

println Transliterator.getInstance(id).transform(anything);
```

**Update per comment:**

```
@Grab(group='com.ibm.icu', module='icu4j', version='58.2')
import com.ibm.icu.text.Transliterator;

String anything = "ш ч с";
String id = "Cyrillic-Latin";

Transliterator.getInstance(id).transform(anything);
```

The code snippet above returns `š č s`; `š` in Latin script transliteration result is indeed a [representation of the sound of "sh"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0). The same is for `č` [which is "ch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8C). I provided `с` here to show the distinction that `s` is returned for it.

The rules that ICU4J does `Cyrillic-Latin` transliteration with is recorded in CLDR project (e.g. see rules for [Cyrillic to Latin](http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/browser/trunk/common/transforms/Cyrillic-Latin.xml)).

To get the output you like to get, you could do another transform with your own customized rules:

```
@Grab(group='com.ibm.icu', module='icu4j', version='58.2')
import com.ibm.icu.text.Transliterator;

String anything = "ш ч с";
String id = "Cyrillic-Latin";

String myRules = "š>sh; č>ch";
Transliterator myTransliterator = Transliterator.createFromRules("myRules", myRules, Transliterator.FORWARD);

myTransliterator.transform(Transliterator.getInstance(id).transform(anything));
```

which outputs `sh ch s`.

You might also decide to define all your rules for Cyrillic from the scratch if you think that better suit your purpose.

Comment: the problem is that some characters are transliterated wrongly like: ш щ ч ц х ф г я - š ŝ č c h f g â . For example ш should be - sh, ч - ch